# White space on the right side of the page below 400px device screen width. How to make it disappear?

Tags: css, icons, footer, display, removing-whitespace

I have two big problems:

The first trouble I have encountered is that when I am testing the responsivity of my website in the contact section I always meet a reappearing problem: There is a white space (.2 rem - 1.2rem width) on the right side of the body when I try to display the whole page under 400px width device.

My second problem is that I have social media icons in the footer. They appear properly in all other sections (multipage website), but only here does something prevent them to be displayed properly. I tried resizing their main divs to 100% width and 100% max-width, but an element is probably still longer than the others, which should obviously cause this kind of problem.

So about the white blank area, I think it is important to know that I have a specially styled scrollbar, which might also cause this little mischief. I am unsure, so I have also tried removing it, but it did not help. In the beginning, I also encountered the same problem with the footer, but somehow I managed to get by and was able to solve it by correcting the width of the .footer-container. Since then the white space appeared and my second problem with social media icons not being displayed properly just arose.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contacts.css">
    <title>Eckert Művek Galéria</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floating-btn show-btn" aria-label="up button" role="button">
        <img src="assets/svg_files/chevron-up-solid.svg" alt="up img" />
    </div>
    <header>
          <!--NAVBAR-->
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu" id="desktop-menu">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.html">Főoldal</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="aboutus.html">Rólunk</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="services.html">Szolgáltatások</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="whyus.html">Miért mi?</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="gallery.html">Galéria</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="contacts.html">Kapcsolat</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--HAMBURGER ICON-->
            <div class="header-right-gap">
                <button class="hamburger" aria-label="hamburger button">
              <div class="line line-1"></div>
              <div class="line line-2"></div>
              <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </button>

            </div>
          </nav>
           <!--MOBILE MENU-->
         <div class="mobile-menu">
            <ul class="m-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.html">Főoldal</a></li> 
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="aboutus.html">Rólunk</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="services.html">Szolgáltatások</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="whyus.html">Miért mi?</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="gallery.html">Galéria</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="contacts.html">Kapcsolat</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
          <!--CONTACT FORM-->
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <h1>Kapcsolat</h1>
    
                <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Családnév" required>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Keresztnév" required>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Telefonszám" required>
                <h4 class="contactus">Lépjen velünk kapcsolatba!</h4>
                <textarea id="texti" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Elküldés" id="button">
    
            </form>
        </div>

        
    </main>
    
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-container">
              <!--COMPANY INFORMATION, CONTATCTS-->
            <div class="footer-top">
                <div>
                    <article>
                        <h2>Elérhetőségeink</h2>
                        <div class="cellphone">
                            <a href="tel:+36709424298"><img src="assets/png/telephone.png" alt="phone-icon"></a>
                            <h3><span>Telefonszám:</span> +36709424298</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="internet">
                            <a href="mailto:eckertmuvek@gmail.com"><img src="assets/png/mail.png" alt="email-icon"></a>
                            <h3><span>E-mail:</span> eckertmuvek@gmail.com</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="headquarter">
                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/png/location.png" alt="company-icon"></a>
                            <h3><span>Telephely:</span> Budapest, 1182 Török Bálint u. 16/b</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="opening-hours">
                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/png/clock.png" alt="op-icon"></a>
                            <h3><span>Nyitvatartási idő:</span> hétfő - péntek(7:00 - 17:30)</h3>
                        </div>
                   
                    </article>

                </div>

                

                <!--TEXT-->
                <div class="text-container">
                    <h4>Céginformációk</h4>
                    <p>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <h5>Cégjegyzékszám: </h5>
                                <p> 01 09 996342</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5>Adószám: </h5>
                                <p>24222716243</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5>Számlaszám: </h5>
                                <p>112131423-43242142-432412421</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5>Cégnév: </h5>
                                <p>Eckert Művek Korlátolt Felelősségű Társaság</p>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--
                    <div class="text-container">
                        <h4>Ttitle-1</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                             Dicta modi laborum quibusdam quis natus debitis qui dolor 
                             voluptatibus ab sit, cum saepe enim unde doloribus veniam 
                             numquam perspiciatis optio impedit.</p>
                    </div>

                -->

                

                <!--POLICIES-->
                <div class="policies">
                    <a href="#">Impresszum</a>
                    <a href="#">GDPR Tájékoztató</a>
                    <a href="#">Süti Tájékoztató</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--MAP-->

            <div class="map">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2699.366130757782!2d19.217992451587673!3d47.42430370844346!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4741c1f21fa88e89%3A0x44673b68b84b51c9!2zQnVkYXBlc3QsIFTDtnLDtmsgQsOhbGludCB1LiAxNmIsIDExODI!5e0!3m2!1shu!2shu!4v1672662477180!5m2!1shu!2shu"
                  height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
            </div>

           <!--SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS-->

            <div class="social-media-icons">
              <div class="sm-container" id="insta">
                  <div class="sm-icon">
                      <a href="images/instagram-logo.svg" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sm-container" id="github">
                  <div class="sm-icon">
                      <a href="images/github-logo.svg" class="fa fa-github"></a>
      
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sm-container" id="facebook">
                  <div class="sm-icon">
                      <a href="images/facebook-logo.svg" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      
                  </div>
              </div>
            <div class="sm-container" id="linkedin">
              <div class="sm-icon">
                  <a href="images/linkedin-logo.svg" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-bottom">
                <p>&copy; Eckert Művek Kft. Minden jog fenntartva.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    <script src="contacts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');



:root {
  --nav-height: 100px; /*80%*/
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}



html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth; 
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  
  }



.floating-btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3.5vh;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0.5));
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.show-btn {
  display: block;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #000;
 
}


/*Srcollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 15px;
  background: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: orangered;
}


nav {
  display: flex; 
  width: min(90%, 1200px);
  height: inherit; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-inline: unset;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 2.5rem;
    gap: 1rem;
    /*margin-top: -2.5rem;*/

}


nav a {
  max-height: var(--nav-height); 
  align-items: center; 
  margin-inline: auto; 
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex; 
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  
}

.nav-item a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: .5em .8em;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

.nav-item a::before,
.nav-item a::after {
  content: '';
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #ffed4b;
  border-right: 3px solid #fdcd3b;
  transform: translate(-100%, 50%); /*-100%, 50%*/
}

.nav-item a:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fdcd3b;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffed4b;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);  /*100%, -50%*/
}

.nav-item a:hover:before,
.nav-item a:hover:after{
  transform: translate(0,0);
  opacity: 1;
}



.nav-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color:yellow;
}

.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 99.vw;
    background: #08071d;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url("assets/images/mainpage/106811484-1608045351058-gettyimages-1126750618-dsc_1540.jpeg") no-repeat center center/cover;
   
}

.container form{
    width: 670px; /*670px*/
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container form h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container form input{
    width: 290px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.container form input::placeholder{
    color: #ddd;
}

.container form #lastName,
.container form #mobile{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.container form h4{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container form textarea{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}

.contactus {
  font-size: 18px;
}



input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, #texti:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fdcd3b;
}


textarea::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 1em;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: rgba(194,194,194,0.713);
}

.container form #button{
    border: 1px solid;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.container form #button:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-block: 4rem;
  color: white;
  
  
 
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: min(90%, 1200px);

  
}

.footer-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer-top h2 {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-top article div {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.footer-top article div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


.footer-top img {
  height: 64px;
}

.text-container p {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.text-container ol li {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  
}
  


/*CONTACT ICONS*/

.cellphone img, .internet img, .headquarter img, .opening-hours img{
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  
  
}

 footer img:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  
  
}


.footer-bottom {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

span {
  color: yellow;
}


.text-container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 20vw;;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

/*POLICIES LINKS*/

.policies {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.policies a {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.policies a:hover {
 color: orangered;
}
/*MAP*/

.map {
  margin-inline: auto;
  
}

/*SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS*/

.social-media-icons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  


}

.sm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding:1rem;
  border: 1px black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sm-container a:active {
  color: yellow;
}

.fa {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: 30px;
  /**/

}




.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  
}



.fa-github {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;

}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #4267B2;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sm-icon {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.sm-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);

}

.fa:hover {
 background-color: #fdcd3b;
}


/*MOBILE MENU*/
.mobile-menu {
    display: none;
}

.mobile-menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; /*.line a szülő tehát 40px a width*/
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translate(-100%);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .mobile-menu-on {
    display: flex; /**/
    transform: translate(0);
  }

  .m-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

   /*hamburger icon*/

   .header-right-gap {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    
   }
  
   .hamburger {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: 1;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
   
    
    
  }

  .hamburger:hover {
    border: 6px solid;
    border-color: yellow;
    width: 43px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
    .hamburger:hover .line.line-1 {
      /*display: none;*/
      transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(7.5px);
      background-color: yellow;
      
    }
    
    .hamburger:hover .line.line-2 {
      display: none;
      
    }
    
    .hamburger:hover .line.line-3 {
      /*display: none;*/
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-7.5px);
      background-color: yellow;
      
      
    }
    
    .line {
    transition: all .4s ease;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-block: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

/*Media query*/

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #desktop-menu {
    display: none;
  }


}

@media (max-width: 900px) {


    footer nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
        
    }

  footer nav ul li a {
    font-size: 15px;
      /*padding: 15px;*/
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }



  footer nav ul li a {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
  }


  .text-container p {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container form {
    width: 470px;
    
  }

  .container form input {
    width: 160px;
  }

  .container form #button, .container form h4 {
    margin-inline: auto;
  }

.container form textarea {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
 
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {

  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }

  .container form {
    max-width: 100%;
    
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .container form input, h4 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .container form input {
    width: 160px;
  }

  .container form #button, .container form h4 {
    margin-inline: auto;
  }

.container form textarea {
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.text-container {
  width: 70vw;
}

.container form #button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  width: 400px;
}




.footer-top {

 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

 
}
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and it was due to **margin** of one element being bigger than it should be, and it just made that div bigger and pushed it out of viewport, so you could check your margins, I can see that you have quite a lot of margins, inline and to margin-right as well.